# PHP file download not recognizing file type in Chrome and Edge

Tags: php, download, http-headers, cross-browser, file-type

I'm trying to create a simple download page, which currently works in Firefox but not entirely in Chrome and Edge. The file to download is an mp3, located in a private directory on the server.

When I download the file in Firefox it works as intended. If I download it using Chrome or Edge the file still downloads, but it doesn't recognize the file type and just saves it as an extensionless file. 
If I add the .mp3 extension manually to the downloaded file it's fine and I can play the track.

These are the headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: private"); 
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath)); 

//Force download
readfile($filePath);
```

Changing the 'Content-type' to **'audio/mpeg'** also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$title\".mp3");
```

to see if the title does not contain the extension

Comment: Well ok didn't know I had to include the extension there... Was somewhat confused since it did work in Firefox. header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.'.mp3"' ); Works perfectly now thank you.

Comment: Better would be to do something like this: $title = $title.".mp3"; and then declare the header Content-Disposition

Comment: I changed it to `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $title .'.'. $ext .'"');` Where `$ext = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` So now it should work with all filetypes